# Get only head values from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a users database in firebase that contains user's first name and last name
[image: Firebase Database]
So, i want to take only the head name (i.e) Stephen, Steve, Tony e.t.c.
And i want to show them as a list in a recycler view.
Is this possible?

This is my java object

```
public class Users {
    String firstName, lastName;

    public Users(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

and i have created my adapter that extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<>`

PS: The names are not always same as the first name.

Comment: I hope you have the Model (Pojo class). Just call only `ArrayList.get(position).getFirstName` in `onBindViewHolder` on Adapter. Otherwise add your current code for clear understanding

Comment: For sure there is. What have you tried so far to achieve that? Show us your code. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @MDEV i don't want to get the first name, i just need the parent nodes of that data

Comment: @AlexMamo I added my java object in the question. till now i'm able to get the first name and last name values and i have created as a recycler view but now i only want the parent elements only.

Comment: I cannot see any code related to how to read the data from the database.

Comment: If your first name is your head name then why not show firstName? Please add complete code where you're getting data.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag. --- In addition: please edit your question to show the code that reads from the database, as it's impossible to say anything about the keys based on your POJO class that you likely only use to read the value of each node.